# How to make bash tab-completion work like windows' cmd.exe?

Tags: macos, bash, bash-completion, iterm2

Say I have a folder with files in it with names like this:

- `log_1.log`
- `log_2.log`
- `log_2.gz`

And I want to perform some operation, let's say move, on log_2.gz.

In Windows cmd.exe, I am used to performing these steps:

1. Type `move` (and nothing else)
2. <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to traverse the tab-complete options until I get to `log_2.gz`
3. Type `destination`

But in bash shell (within iTerm2 on Mac OS X 10.8.3), I have to do something like this:

1. Type `mv l`
2. <kbd>tab</kbd> which takes me to `log_` and makes an annoying beep sound
3. Type `2`
4. <kbd>tab</kbd> which takes me to `log_2.` and makes an annoying beep sound
5. Type `g`
6. <kbd>tab</kbd> which takes me to `log_2.gz` and is satisfyingly silent
7. Type `destination`

As you can see, bash requires many more steps even when you know the destination filename, but imagine a scenario where you are not really certain what exactly is in the filename (maybe the `ls` was too long).  I often find myself in this scenario after a few <kbd>tab</kbd> + typing and am forced to abandon the command, run `ls` again, copy the filename, maybe even run a `pwd` to concatenate with the folder, and then resume where I left off.  This is very annoying.

Comment: If you had 50 files in your folder you'd be hitting tab on average 25 times, but with bash's partial completion you're going to be hitting the tab key a lot less on average. Your case above is skewed to the minority of cases where find the file using cmd.exe tab is quicker.

Comment: I disagree with your assumption of which cases are minority.

Comment: Try zsh, with the `menucomplete` (I think) option

Answer (score 13):

You can add the following in your `.inputrc` (if you don't have one, then create it) file. Once added, either source the file or logout and log back in.

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on
TAB: menu-complete
```

Comment: Nice! I realized a new scenario: In windows when I type `cd` <kbd>tab</kbd> it will only cycle thru directories, so it's smart about file-types.  Any tips on this?

Comment: This link should be a good source. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html

Comment: I love this--the new scenario I'd like is to skip the .hidden files. I have way too many of those. But if I know at least the first character of the file I'm interested in, I know I won't be tabbing more than 7 times before trying another way! Thanks!

Comment: The `show-all-if-ambiguous` option can be useful, but deviates from what Windows does.

Comment: NOTE: if you create `~/.inputrc`, be sure to `$include /etc/inputrc` at the top, otherwise the user's copy will just override the system one.